# Unclear neo4j.properties store_dir effect when running in embedded mode

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to use the "store_dir" property available for use in neo4j.properties file for externalizing where the embedded neo4j should store its files. However when using the newEmbeddedDatabaseBuiler you need to already specify the db location during instantiation:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = factory
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("data/graph.db")
            .loadPropertiesFromFile("conf/neo4j.properties")
            .newGraphDatabase();
```

Is there any available provision to make the store_dir also work in embedded mode?

[kernel configuration settings](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/kernel-configuration.html)

Comment: Don't think so. The value seems to be overridden. This could be a nice feature request, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (not tested, be aware):

```
Properties props = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream("conf/neo4j.properties"));
GraphDatabase graphDb = factory
        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(props.getProperty("store_dir")
        .setConfig(props)    // maybe some casting from Properties to Map<String,String> necessary here
        .newGraphDatabase();
```